# MySQL query is taking too long and unable to retrieve the data

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've tried multiple ways of running below query but it doesn't extract the output as shown below. I've tried to check execution plan of it which looks fine.

[image]

My code:

```
SELECT
SUM(case when cp.payment_method_id_fk = 3 then dt.amount_attempted else 0 end)  AS Subsequent_successDeduction_TIGO,
SUM(case when cp.payment_method_id_fk = 2 then dt.amount_attempted else 0 end)  AS Subsequent_successDeduction_MTN,
   date(dt.transaction_date) AS DateOfTransactions
FROM deduction_transactions dt INNER JOIN customer_deductions cd ON
   dt.deduction_id_fk = cd.id INNER JOIN customer_policy cp ON
   cd.cust_policy_id = cp.customer_policy_id
   inner join  policy_info pi ON cp.policy_id_fk = pi.id
inner join product_info pr on pi.product_id_fk=pr.id
where
   date(dt.transaction_date)=date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) and dt.status=1 and date(cp.created_date) <> date(curdate()) and cp.payment_confirmed_date <> dt.transaction_date
GROUP BY DateOfTransactions;
```

Comment: try debugging it by removing joins or clauses or conditions one by one! Check the relationships once again. And Case in a SUM is time consuming operation!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your filtering predicate:

```
date(dt.transaction_date)=date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day)
```

It suffers from the "expression on the left side of the equal sign" syndrome. This prevents the optimizer to use an index. Change this condition to:

```
dt.transaction_date >= date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day) and
dt.transaction_date < curdate()
```

This way the optimizer can make good use of an index if it's present. Therefore, make sure the you have an index on `transaction_date` and `status`, as in:

```
create index ix1 on deduction_transactions (transaction_date, status);
```